# Order-independent substitution

Tags: regex, awk, sed, substitution

I have a file with entries like this:

```
server: 11.11.11.11
port: 1111

port: 2222
server: 22.22.22.22
```

Each entry is separated by a blank line. Sometimes, the order of `port` and `server` is inverted (like in the example).

I would like to reorganize this file to obtain:

```
11.11.11.11:1111
22.22.22.22:2222
```

Is it possible to sort the file? Can I match this structure with sed or awk ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F ': *' 'function prnt() {
   print a["server"] ":" a["port"]
}
NF==2 {
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{
   prnt()
   delete a
}
END {
   prnt()
}' file
```

**Explanation:**

By using `FS=': *'` we are splitting each line into 2 fields. When `NF==2` we populate an array `a` with key as `$1` (server or port) and `$2` as value. `next` will move to next record.

When `NF==2` is false then we are calling `prnt` function to just print the data from array `a`. `split` will empty previously held values in `a`. Finally we call `prnt` in `END` block to print last record of data.

**Output:**

```
11.11.11.11:1111
22.22.22.22:2222
```